# php file download script doesn't work with iOS7 device?

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, ios7, download

I have the follow php script to trigger auto downlad.

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $file = 'sample.jpg';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type:  application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

http://toasterlab.net/liese/

it works properly on desktop and my android phone, but not on my iPad and iPhone.

what should I do to get it works on iPad & iphone?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's an iPhone browser's issue and not that much of the code..somebody prove me if i'm wrong.

Comment: but not only safari, the chrome on iPad doesn't work either

Comment: iOS7 does not allow auto implementation. You will need to assign a click event to it.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? We are having the same issue now that users have updated to iOS7. Safari shows this helpful error "Safari cannot open the page because the network connection was lost." It might have something to do with SSL as the exact same code works on a non https connection.

Comment: As @Vector has mentioned, iOS devices don't support file auto-download. The only solution is to ask user to save the picture on their own

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line where you set the Content-Length, like this:

```
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

... I haven't dug deeper but right now that's working for me on iPad iOS 7.0.4

Comment: This solution worked for me as well on a related problem. The script worked fine for any browser except Safari. Removing the Content-Length header fixed it and it seems to work with all browsers now. 

(Warning - I performed only limited testing. There may be some negative consequences of removing Content-Length)