# PHP | Download the PDF file, works on Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: php

Hi guys I have a mini problem, I don't understand the solution, I have an area dedicated to the user where he can download his files in PDF, everything works perfectly on Chrome, but not on Safari, I put the code:

filepdf.php:

```
<?php
while($row_rit_acc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_rit_acconto_dfpagate)){ ?>
<?php
$icona_donwload = "<i class='fas fa-file-download'></i>";
$doc = $row_rit_acc['cont_id'];
<td><?php echo "<a href='downloads_doc_contabilita.php?ritacc_df=".$doc."'>".'Download '.$icona_donwload."</a>"; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

downloads_doc_contabilita.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connection/cnt.php';



if (isset($_GET['ritacc_df'])) {
    $id = $_GET['ritacc_df'];

    // fetch file to download from database

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bigo_contabilita WHERE cont_id =$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connessione, $sql);

    $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $filepath = 'uploads/' . $file['cont_richiesta_rit'];

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('uploads/' . $file['cont_richiesta_rit']));
        readfile('uploads/' . $file['cont_richiesta_rit']);


        exit;
    }

}
```

what can it depend on?

Comment: did you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587520/php-file-download-script-doesnt-work-with-ios7-device) ?

Comment: @RafaelDouradoD write your comment to answer, cause i don 't know. But work hahahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587520/php-file-download-script-doesnt-work-with-ios7-device) removing `Content-Length` from `header` must solve your problem.